# Can't install/uninstall/repair ADO.NET 2 Provider for SQLite (C#)

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net

I'm trying to work with a SQLite database in C#, using the ADO.NET 2 Provider from this [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/) as suggested in this [tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/157830-using-sqlite-with-c#/).

I think I messed up the installation. It doesn't find a class and I tried several wrappers from different sources, so I would like to reinstall, but I can't seem to remove or repair it. 
When I try to uninstall, first it asks me for the `System.Data.SQLite.DLL`, which I don't think I have, then it prompts me an error "**There is a problem with this Windows Installer package, a program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.**"

Trying to repair gives me the error **"A network error occured while attempting to read from the file C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpD938.tmp.msi**"

Can someone who uses this ADO.NET 2 Provider please tell me where the program normally installs to, and perhaps upload the `System.Data.SQLite.DLL` so I can try to uninstall with that? I'm on Windows 7.

Thanks (and sorry for this beginneresque question but I just wasted countless hours on trying to uninstall this properly by myself.)

Comment: Why not using the NuGet package instead? It's so much easier and doesn't require you to install anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you using the NuGet package. In the Package Manager Console type:

```
Install-Package System.Data.SQLite
```

This will add reference to the `System.Data.SQLite` assembly and add the x86 and x64 unmanaged libraries to your project.

Now you could directly start working with it:

```
using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=mydb.db;"))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "...";
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try that.

Comment: Yup, that worked nicely. Thanks again. Accepting your answer for being the solution although one could be nitpicky etc., I hope this isn't wrong.